# Angular Material: autocomplete not working without cache with $resource response

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

So it's basically what the question says, i have a function that returns a response from `$resource` which fetches from server.

```
var user = $resource(apiHost + '/users/:action/:query', {query: '@query'}, {
    search: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
        params: {
            action: 'search',
            query: '@query'
        }
    }
});
self.search = function(name){
    return user.search({query: name}, function(result){
        return result;
    });
}
```

these functions are inside a service, i say this just to clear some confusions

now, in controller, where i am making the call to service function

```
$scope.searchUser = function(name){
    return userService.search(name);
};
```

it seems simple, but i have to admit i don't find any problem this far.

now in html where `autocomplete` is rendered

```
<md-autocomplete md-no-cache="true" md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-items="user in searchUser(searchText)" md-item-text="user.name">
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{user.name}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

now from here. i am not sure if the problem comes from here. but when i type something in `autocomplete`, nothing shows.. and i have been making sure the server is getting the requests i need to make.

I have tried without the attribute `md-no-cache` and the effects are kind of different. When some text is entered. nothing is shown.. but when part of the text is deleted, the `autocomplete` shows the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to return the promise of your ngResource call in your `searchUser()` function:

```
$scope.searchUser = function(name){
    return userService.search(name).$promise;
};
```

Comment: oh.. i thought it was not necessary because i thought it was already returning a promise, i must learn more about promises, could you please provide a book or tutorial about promises?

Comment: From the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource): It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. The Resource instances and collections have the `$http` promise with `$promise` as an additional property.